# Prism - Published Event not being subscribed

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am writing my code in WPF where I have two view models. In one view model, I am closing a prism pop up window and on close I am calling my publishing method like:

```
private void OnCancelInteraction()
{
   _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent>().Publish();
   this.FinishInteraction();
}
```

while my subscribe event goes like this:

```
public ResidentListViewModel(IResidentService residentService, IUserService userService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    var res =   eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent>().Subscribe(InitializeCollectionView);
     _residentService = residentService;
     _userService = userService;
     _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
     InitializeCollectionView();

     //***The InteractionRequest class 
     FormDialogOpenRequest = new InteractionRequest<INotification>();
     ConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>();

        //*** Commands for each of the buttons
     RaiseFormDialogOpenCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.RaiseFormDialogOpen);
     aiseConfirmationCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.RaiseConfirmation);
 }
```

Here is how both of these classes are receiving event aggregator:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
var aggregator = container.Resolve<EventAggregator>();
this.DataContext = new ResidentFormDialogViewModel(residentService, userService, unitService, aggregator);
```

here is my second class:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
var aggregator = container.Resolve<EventAggregator>();
DataContext = new ResidentListViewModel(residentService, userService, aggregator);
```

Every time I cancel my interaction, the publishing gets published but `ResidentListViewModel` is not being called as for subscribing.

`ResidentListViewModel` is being called before the other class which has subscribe method. Could it be a problem? All I want is to Initialize my collection view whenever the interaction gets finished without breaking the MVVM Pattern? If there is any other method please do suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to configure _eventAggregator object to be Singleton and use this single instance in both the viewmodels. The problem in your case may be related to different EventAggregator objects being used to Publish and Subscribe the event.

Comment: @NaveedZahoor I see that UnityContainer is giving 2 different instances of EventAggregator to each class. You should configure eventAggregator as singleton.

Comment: for example, you can use : container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator,EventAggregator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); Also, you could use a class giving you singleton instance of EventAggregator through static method .

Comment: Might be helpful to somebody: one gotchya that I've snagged myself on twice now is that IContainerProvider is perfectly happy to return a reference to a class derived from PubSubEvent.  Bypassing IEventAggregator to get the event instance was obviously not what I wanted, but the system will chug along just fine and I'll be left scratching my head wondering why my subscriptions aren't getting called.